# My VB.NET code to download a file doesnt download the file entirely

Tags: vb.net

so i have been having some issues with downloading a file in vb.net. its for an auto-updater but it doesn't download it entirely. It's file size is only a few KB when the program is about 2 MB. This is the code i have currently:

```
Try
    My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("dropboxlink directly to the file 'dl=1'", My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments & "/Updated/" & LatestVersion & ".exe")
    MsgBox("The update has been downloaded!" & vbNewLine & "The application will now Exit and Re-open with the new version! :D")
    Diagnostics.Process.Start(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments & "/Updated/" & LatestVersion & ".exe")
    Application.Exit()
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("OH MY! An error occured while trying to download the update.")
End Try
```

I just don't understand why it does this. its very aggravating!
anyone have the same problem at some point and know what to do to fix it or what im doing wrong?

-thanks, Nick

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: I don't get any exceptions or errors when it downloads so i really have no idea whats wrong with it. the only error I DO get is when it trys to open it and it says something along the lines of 'unsupported 16-bit application' but that's due to it not downloading the entire file i believe.

Comment: @user3630916: This may sound like a silly thing to check, but is "dropboxlink directly to the file 'dl=1'" a fully qualified URL? What happens when you paste this link in a new browser window? Does the file download completely without a user being logged in or supplying username and password?

Comment: Yes, when i go to the dropbox link, it pulls up the download popup saying save or run? so yes it should just work. it has the dl pram enabled like it should be.

Comment: Anyone? its been a long time and no help T_T